# Directory.Build.Props is not overriding property in nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget-package, csproj

I am developing a WinForms application in Visual Studio 2017. I have a nuget package which contains a props file which causes a compiler error to happen if the platform is set to AnyCPU. However, there are times when I want to ignore this error, such as when I am using the Visual Designer, which fails to work when the configuration is x64. (That is a well known limitation).

The relevant part of the nuget props file is:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      SpeechPlatformCheck;
      $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="SpeechPlatformCheck">
    <Error Condition="'$(Platform.ToLower())' == 'anycpu'" Text="Cognitive Services Speech SDK doesn't support 'Any CPU' as a platform." />
  </Target>
```

I know this will all work fine, because if I manually edit the nuget props file the compile works and I can use the Visual Designer. (When we actually deploy the app we switch to x64 which also works fine). This is *only* a problem when using the Visual Designer.

I am attempt to override the nuget props file by adding a **Directory.Build.props** file to my csproj file, as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>true</BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Currently this is not working. I know for sure my Directory.Build.props file is being included early in the compile process. I've tried lots of permutations, setting it true/false/empty. I tried to see if I could override the "SpeechPlatformCheck" target. All to no avail.

My work-around is to hack the nuget props file, which I would rather not do. What can I do here? Is the nuget props file being processed last and trumping anything I attempt to do in my own props file?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you can create a `Directory.Build.targets` file and override the target:

```
<Target Name="SpeechPlatformCheck" />
```

The `BuildDependsOn` property is not meant to be set to true/false or any individual value, it is a list of targets to execute. If you want to remove this target from the build, you could also use some string replace functions to remove the target (also from a `Directory.Build.targets` file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn.Replace('SpeechPlatformCheck;', '')</BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Either way, this does not guarantee that the compilation will result in a usable output (depending on what the Speech SDK does).